# How to mock a service and all the autowired fields in the service?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, integration-testing

I am looking to Mock my service and all the autowired fields in it. Below is the service:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("propvalues")
   Map<String,String> propvalues;
   ...
   ...
}
```

Below is the Configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class MyValuesConfig {
    @Bean(name = "propvalues")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mysvcvalues")
    private Map<String,String> propvalues;
}
```

The configuration class reads from application-myvalues.yml

This is my Test class MyServiceImplTest

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyServiceImplTest {
    @Mock
    private MyService myService;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Now I find that the autowired fields in the mock service is null. Ideally I would want to see the values loaded from the configuration in the Map in the mock service.

Comment: why do you need that? The main idea is you need to setup result/exception for particular method call of mocked class, fields do not make sense it that case.

Comment: The service needs those values. They should not be null.

Comment: To expand on @AndreyB.Panfilov comment: we should not mock the unit under test, only its dependencies. In the given service, this is not (simply) possible since we use field injection. I would recommend to use [constructor injection](https://www.baeldung.com/constructor-injection-in-spring) instead, and then only mock the dependencies.

Comment: Does that mean I have to refactor the code of the Service class itself?

Comment: If possible, yes. Otherwise, we would have to use [`@Mock` and `@InjectMocks`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/mockito-injectmocks-mocks-dependency-injection).

Comment: Consider code that is hard (relatively) to test as a code smell.  _Does that mean I have to refactor the code of the Service class itself?_  **YES!**

Comment: Which version of spring you're using? maybe ```spay``` works for your problem

Comment: Spring Boot 2.5.5

Comment: Then I think ```Spy``` will work in your situation.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `@Mock` user `@SpyBean`

`@SpyBean` inject object like an actual bean but you can mock any of its parts separately.

Or you can use `spy` to initialize the object and mock the other parts that you want.
Something like:
`Mokito.spy(myService).when(....).thenReturn(...)`

Comment: code does not compile